How to add config file in window installer
I have a window application in vs 2022 and also setup the installer (.msi) with application. It is working fine till now but as per new requirement i need to add config file and add all credential over there. I added there and now my application is correctly reading values from app.config but problem is when i create Installer (.msi) after install that on another machine then application is not reading value from app.config file. I don't want to use any third party tool. Please help on this

What tool or project did you use to create the msi? Do you mean the application reads the value from app.config or the msi reads from config?

Thank you for your response. I am using the following tool: "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022". I mean to say application reading the value correctly from the app.config file but when i create msi file and that msi file not able to read value from app.config

Did you rebuild the installer project? Is there <AppName>.exe.config file in the installed location? And check whether the content of <AppName>.exe.config is consistent with app.config.

Yes I did. but there is not file there with the name "*.config"

Is App.config added the Application project? May I know how do you add a reference to the Application project in the Installer project? Did you select View -> File System -> Application Folder -> Project Output -> Primary Output?

I added app.config in window application (i.e. application project) but i have not added any reference in Installer. Can you tell me the steps how i can add this because in above step i have not found "Primary Output" in the option

App.config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="MySetting" value="HelloWorld" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>

Windows App: read config sample
//using System.Configuration;
    string mySettingValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MySetting"];
    MessageBox.Show("MySetting value: " + mySettingValue);

Right click installer project ->  View -> File system

Right click Application Folder -> Add -> Project output

Select the  Windows app project - > Primary output


Thank you for your answer. Let me check and will update you

Thank you for your answer. I did the same step and created the installer. when I install installer (.msi) on machine. I click on the button  and I was getting the following error: "Object reference not set to an instance.". but not picking the value from app.config.

I can't reproduce your issue. Can you share minimal sample app and installer project that reproduce the issue on GitHub?

Thank you for your response. Due to company norms. I cannot share the current app let me create the sample app and will share it with you.

I created one new application and found that it is working fine and picking the value of app.cofig from installer. but I don't know what happen with my existing application and It is not picking the data from app.config.very strange for me..

Now that you have a working version, you can gradually move the old project code to the new project. Maybe related to the cache. Try uninstalling the old version.

Actually version is correct Desktop application is in .Net core 6 and using Visual Studio 2022 installer.but still the same challenge.
